# How capture image from ip camera with PHP

Tags: php, ip-camera

So far i have this code which never stop loading

camera.php

```
$img = 'http://userid:password@ipaddress/mjpgstreamreq/1/image.jpg'; 
header ('content-type: image/jpeg'); 
readfile( $img );
```

index.html

```
<img src="camera.php" />
<!-- But this does not work -->
```

and if I have in a img tag on the page with this url as the src also never stop loading the page, and I am trying to read just the snapshot it is not a continues frames this is a recorded picture took with the ip camera, that I want to read and save in a file for future needs, and I am at localhost and the ip camera is in another network if it matters, so how can I read this without this continues loading.

Comment: So, do the people know they are on camera?

Comment: The whole idea behind this is that I am trying to do a way to avoid the popup asking for login information, so everybody can see the latest picture of construction site and they know that the cameras are working there, I just want to display the image on a website

Comment: You should probably use PHP as an HTTP proxy.

Comment: I try to use one php proxy from a guy on github no success at all

Comment: [link](https://github.com/zyphlar/ip-camera-proxy/blob/master/snapshot.php) and this is link for proxy on github

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out, but remember to change the username, password, ip and port on your Ip cam

```
<img src="http://myServer.com/cam.php" width="640" height="380" name="refresh">

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">     
  image = "http://myServer.com/cam.php"
  function Start() {
   tmp = new Date();
   tmp = "?"+tmp.getTime()
   document.images["refresh"].src = image+tmp
   setTimeout("Start()", 1000)
  }
    Start();       
</script>

<?php
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 $img="IPCAM_IP:PORT/snapshot.cgi?user=UserName&pwd=Password"; 
 header ('content-type: image/jpeg');
 readfile($img); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The resource you are requesting using `readfile()` is a [motion JPEG stream](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_JPEG), not just a single image. As such, the `readfile()` operation will never end — it will just keep on spitting out more images as the stream continues!

You will need to implement code to open the resource as an HTTP stream, parse out a single JPEG from the stream, and stop reading. This may not be simple.

Comment: do you have any idea how i might set up a loop to just a get jpg from this mjpg